# Find processes by parent PID on Solaris

Tags: unix, process, solaris, ps

I'd like to find all processes running on Unix (Solaris) with a certain PPID. Is this possible using the `ps` command?

Comment: Try `ps -e -o pid,ppid | nawk '{ if ($2 == the_ppid_you_want) print $1; }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could always perform a grep on the output of the process list;

`ps -ef | grep XXXX`, where `XXXX` is your PPID.

This will at least give you a list of processes with that number, and knowing that `PPID` should be the third column, lead you to your specified Parent Process ID.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (12.04 at least) you can use the `--ppid` option. E.g.

```
ps --ppid 1234
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get "ps: illegal option -- ppid"

Comment: What OS are you using? The `--ppid` option works for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It's Unix - Solaris 10

Comment: I can't find a similar option on the Solaris man pages (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ps-1.html) sorry. You might have to do it using `grep` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris 5.10:

For the current process

> ps -o ppid -p $$

For a process with PID 12345

> ps -o ppid -p 12345